Как написать распознавание текста с фото, если один шрифт считывает, а другие нет
Написал простой скрипт для распознавания текста с фото, но есть одно но:

Такой шрифт без проблем он разбирает,
нужный мне шрифт:

Вообще не разбирает, результат выдаёт:

Распознанный текст: с0 сорок 'сся )ебясол се  еся" "]ш
Исправленный текст: со сорок вся ебясол се вся я


Код:
import easyocr
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
import re

def recognize_and_correct_text(image_path):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['ru']) 
    result = reader.readtext(image_path, detail=0)
        
    recognized_text = ' '.join(result)
    print(f"Распознанный текст: {recognized_text}")
        
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\s]', '', recognized_text)
        
    spell = SpellChecker(language='ru')
        
    words = cleaned_text.split()
        
    corrected_text = []
    for word in words:
        if spell.candidates(word):
            corrected_word = spell.correction(word)
            corrected_text.append(corrected_word)
        else:
            corrected_text.append(word)
        
    final_corrected_text = ' '.join(corrected_text)
    print(f"Исправленный текст: {final_corrected_text}")
        
    return final_corrected_text

image_path = 'p.png'

final_text = recognize_and_correct_text(image_path)
print(f"Окончательный текст: {final_text}")


Можно посмотреть в сторону тесеракта, можно подумать в сторону дообучения под конкретный шрифт.. можно попытаться подготовить само изображение - увеличить размер картинки, программно исправить перспективу букв, что бы они стали больше походить на печатные. В общем, однозначного ответа не дать.

Шрифт сложный. Конкретно под него нужно учить. Да и то я не уверен в результате.

Вопрос интересный, но мне самому пришлось чуть присмотреться чтоб прочитать нормально)
Оптимальный вариант, мне кажется, учить конкретно под ваш шрифт

Похоже, появился новый темин - ебясол.

@rotabor Да там вся фраза "со сорок вся ебясол се вся я" прекрасна
